# Command Palette not showing up in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Apparently the shortcut for the command palette in Visual Studio code is Ctrl+Shift+P, but that shortcut isn't working, even though all other shortcuts work. It isn't showing up in the top taskbar either. I've checked and there aren't any other programs receiving the command. Anything I can do about this? Version is Visual Studio Code 2022

Comment: Visual Studio is something very different from VS Code. Maybe you're confusing the two? As far as I know, the thing that's the closest to the command palette from VS Code is the Search (`Ctrl+Q` by default).

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Comment: @starball No, the problem is I can't access the command palette

Answer (score 0):

Check that the shortcut is properly defined by VSCode.
In keybindings.json, search for the command associated with the key `ctrl+shift+p`. If you do not find anything, add this line to your keybindings.json file:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+p",          "command": "workbench.action.showCommands" }
```

Note that you can still access the command palette using `ctrl+p` (wich will open a quick file browser) and then type `>`.